# Converting compact cache v2 to TPKX

Tags: tile-package, arcgis-enterprise

Is TPKX a zip file archive of compact cache v2?
Yes uncompressed

Trying to find some specifications document
I have developed script to build Compact Cache v2 .bundle files from standard XYZ OR TMS raster  map tiles. **Need to convert that folder structure to TPKX**
I have some clients that want to use runtime apps as well as serve the raster tile cache with ArcGIS enterprise 
https://www.reddit.com/r/gis/comments/cj5nny/can_you_convert_compact_cache_v2_to_tpkx_is_tpkx/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share

Answer (score 2):

From [What's new in ArcGIS Enterprise 10.7.1](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/get-started/latest/windows/what-s-new-in-arcgis-enterprise.htm):

> **New tile package format**
>
> ArcGIS Enterprise 10.7 includes a new tile package file format with
>   the extension .tpkx. In this format, cache tiles are stored using the
>   optimized compactv2 storage format. This format has a simplified file
>   structure and provides better performance when accessed over network
>   file shares and cloud store directories.